# Flutter parsed nested list of object

Tags: flutter, dart

How to parsed this response of json

```
{
    "name_of_data_dummy_one": false,
    "name_of_data_dummy_two": "1",
    "name_of_data_dummy_three": 1,
    "name_of_data": [
        {
            "name_of_data_one": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_two": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_three": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_four": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_five": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_six": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_seven": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_eight": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_nine": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_ten": "bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            "name_of_data_one": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_two": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_three": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_four": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_five": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_six": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_seven": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_eight": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_nine": "bla bla bla",
            "name_of_data_ten": "bla bla bla"
        }
    ]
}
```

And heres the code for access the api

```
Future<Either<String, List<CompanyListResponseModel>>> getCompanyList(
      GetListCompanyModel companyListModel) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('URL'),
      body: thisIsModel.toJson(),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     return Right(List<CompanyListResponseModel>.from(jsonDecode(response.body)
        .map((x) => CompanyListResponseModel.fromJson(x))));
    } else {
      return const Left('get product error');
    }
  }
```

I have generated response data like the example in quicktype.io loks like this

```
class CompanyListResponseModel {
bool? nameOfDataDummyOne;
String? nameOfDataDummyTwo;
int? nameOfDataDummyThree;
List<NameOfDatum>? nameOfData;

CompanyListResponseModel({
    this.nameOfDataDummyOne,
    this.nameOfDataDummyTwo,
    this.nameOfDataDummyThree,
    this.nameOfData,
});

factory CompanyListResponseModel.fromRawJson(String str) => 
CompanyListResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

factory CompanyListResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> 
json) => CompanyListResponseModel(
    nameOfDataDummyOne: json["name_of_data_dummy_one"],
    nameOfDataDummyTwo: json["name_of_data_dummy_two"],
    nameOfDataDummyThree: json["name_of_data_dummy_three"],
    nameOfData: json["name_of_data"] == null ? [] : 
List<NameOfDatum>.from(json["name_of_data"]!.map((x) => 
NameOfDatum.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name_of_data_dummy_one": nameOfDataDummyOne,
    "name_of_data_dummy_two": nameOfDataDummyTwo,
    "name_of_data_dummy_three": nameOfDataDummyThree,
    "name_of_data": nameOfData == null ? [] : 
List<dynamic>.from(nameOfData!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}

class NameOfDatum {
String? nameOfDataOne;
String? nameOfDataTwo;
String? nameOfDataThree;
String? nameOfDataFour;
String? nameOfDataFive;
String? nameOfDataSix;
String? nameOfDataSeven;
String? nameOfDataEight;
String? nameOfDataNine;
String? nameOfDataTen;

NameOfDatum({
    this.nameOfDataOne,
    this.nameOfDataTwo,
    this.nameOfDataThree,
    this.nameOfDataFour,
    this.nameOfDataFive,
    this.nameOfDataSix,
    this.nameOfDataSeven,
    this.nameOfDataEight,
    this.nameOfDataNine,
    this.nameOfDataTen,
});

factory NameOfDatum.fromRawJson(String str) => 
NameOfDatum.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

factory NameOfDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
NameOfDatum(
    nameOfDataOne: json["name_of_data_one"],
    nameOfDataTwo: json["name_of_data_two"],
    nameOfDataThree: json["name_of_data_three"],
    nameOfDataFour: json["name_of_data_four"],
    nameOfDataFive: json["name_of_data_five"],
    nameOfDataSix: json["name_of_data_six"],
    nameOfDataSeven: json["name_of_data_seven"],
    nameOfDataEight: json["name_of_data_eight"],
    nameOfDataNine: json["name_of_data_nine"],
    nameOfDataTen: json["name_of_data_ten"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name_of_data_one": nameOfDataOne,
    "name_of_data_two": nameOfDataTwo,
    "name_of_data_three": nameOfDataThree,
    "name_of_data_four": nameOfDataFour,
    "name_of_data_five": nameOfDataFive,
    "name_of_data_six": nameOfDataSix,
    "name_of_data_seven": nameOfDataSeven,
    "name_of_data_eight": nameOfDataEight,
    "name_of_data_nine": nameOfDataNine,
    "name_of_data_ten": nameOfDataTen,
  };
}
```

and I got error like this "Unhandled Exception: type 'List < dynamic >' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"

My expectation is to create a listview, constrained in parsing data as in the example, by the way I use bloc state management

Comment: Do you really have 4 identical keys of "name_of_data"?

Comment: It's also hard to help without seeing what `CompanyListResponseModel` looks like

Comment: i've add my CompanyResponseModel, generated from quicktype.io. The JSON response is the same as the original data, it's just a different name

Comment: i don't know how to parsed response to the CompanyListResponseModel,

Answer (score 1):

Your response is just a single `CompanyListResponseModel` but you treat it as a if it's a list, which it's not. Change you function to

```
Future<Either<String, CompanyListResponseModel>> getCompanyList(
      GetListCompanyModel companyListModel) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('URL'),
      body: thisIsModel.toJson(),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     return CompanyListResponseModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)));
    } else {
      return const Left('get product error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: i'm sorry, my CompanyListResponseModel is not complete, i,ve changed it